# how to use variable in response.write function?

Tags: html, vbscript

The code makes value of radiobuttons "i" as string. It should print `i` as variable like 1-2-3.

```
For i=1 To 40
Response.Write("<td height='30' align='center'>x")
Else
Response.Write("<td height='30' align='center'><input type=radio name=asd value="i">")
End If
next
```

Comment: Please fix the If/Else/End If.

Answer (score 0):

You use a variable in `response.write` in the exact same way you use it with every other string:

```
Response.Write "<td height='30' align='center'>" & _
  "<input type=radio name=asd value='" & i & "'>"
```

This is documented in the [VBScript tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info).